# "IN" Function not work properly

Tags: php, sql, function, search

i want find a value in one of structure in database but my code not work properly

```
// $dir_id = 2;
// dirs (in database) = 1,2,3

SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE (id='$id' && $dir_id IN(`dirs`)) ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

but this code cant find 2 it just find 1 in `dirs`

how i can resolve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `IN` you will past the list of ids you want to match for example

```
AND dirs IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

With your example:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` 
WHERE id='$id' 
AND dirs IN ('$dir_id')
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE (id='$id' && $dir_id IN(Select 'column_name' from `dirs`)) ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stored string `"1,2,3"` in the `dirs` column. (*Through you should normalize you db design.*)

Then you can't use `IN`, you need to use **[FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)** instead.

```
SELECT * FROM `items` 
WHERE (id='$id' AND FIND_IN_SET('$dir_id', `dirs`)) 
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```